# Data Center migration

Tags: cisco-nexus, data-center

We have two data centers in different locations and we want to transfer DC2 (secondary Data Center) from location Y to location X where X is DC1 (Primary) location.  The connection between both data centers is p2p and we implemented OTV between them to extend VLANs, so now we will have VDC-DC2 in location X.

We need to connect both DC1 and DC2 in location X together but we are facing an issue:

1. Because DC2 is the secondary, we have the same Vlans IDs that are in DC1.
2. Each DC has a different network.
3. We are not going to transfer all the applications -- only part of them so we still need to keep both vlans and networks in both DCs.

How can we fix this issue? Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You can use the same VLAN numbers if the VLANs are separated by layer-3 (router, layer-3 switch). VLANs are layer-2 constructs that are bounded by layer-3. The numbers only matter until layer-3. In fact, even on the same router, if you have multiple router interfaces, you could use the same VLAN number off each router layer-3 interface.

Comment: OTV breaks that by extending L2 across the L3 link.

Comment: It's also possible to map dissimilar VLAN numbers across OTV - either as a native function of the protocol or (if using F3/M3) using VLAN translation.

Comment: I was thinking to: 1. Create Vlan networl layer 3 as a secondary in the DC1.2.advertise the networks in DC2 through DC1, Anything would to access DC2 will be through DC1 via OTV. 3. when i move all the servers and apps to DC1 i will start to change the vlans ID. but this will cause a traffic issue. now the users global will access the data center through DC1 instead of using MPLS direct to DC2. how i can fix this.Any ideas